# Masstransit add consumer in container by specifying queue binding

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am having the following consumer type:

```
internal class ObjectAddedHandler : IConsumer<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent> context)
    {
        var @event = context.Message;
        await HandleAsync(@event).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

which is registered in my container through:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(configurationProvider.RabbitMQHostName, hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Username(configurationProvider.RabbitMQUsername);
            hostConfigurator.Password(configurationProvider.RabbitMQPassword);

            hostConfigurator.UseCluster(c =>
            {
                string[] hostnames = configurationProvider.RabbitMQNodes.Split(';');
                c.ClusterMembers = hostnames;
            });
        });

        host.Settings.GetConnectionFactory().Endpoint.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;

        /*HERE*/ x.AddConsumer<ObjectAddedHandler>().Endpoint(e => e.Name = "ObjectAddedHandler "+configurationProvider.TenantName);

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(container);
    }));

});
```

however by following the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#routing-key) I would like to setup a **direct exchange** in order to use routing keys. Couldn't find anywhere in the documentation how to add the consumer in the way I do and at the same time setting the binding properties of the endpoint as reported in the documentation.

When I try to access the endpoint in adding the consumer I can only modify the name, the prefetch count and a couple of more properties but nothing more. However I would like to set my endpoints to accept messages only with routing key **tenantName**. Is there a way by any chance?

**EDIT**:

Publisher side:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(() => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {

        cfg.Send<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent>(routingCfg => {
            routingCfg.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(config => ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("TenantCode"));
        });
        cfg.Message<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent>(routingCfg => routingCfg.SetEntityName("ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent"));
        cfg.Publish<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent>(routingCfg => routingCfg.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct);


        var host = cfg.Host(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQHostName"), hostConfigurator =>
        {
#if !DEBUG
            hostConfigurator.Username(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQUsername"));
            hostConfigurator.Password(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQPassword"));

            hostConfigurator.UseCluster(c =>
            {
                string[] hostnames = ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQNodes").Split(';');
                c.ClusterMembers = hostnames;
            });
#endif
        });
    }));
});
```

Receiver side:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(configurationProvider.RabbitMQHostName, hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Username(configurationProvider.RabbitMQUsername);
            hostConfigurator.Password(configurationProvider.RabbitMQPassword);

            hostConfigurator.UseCluster(c =>
            {
                string[] hostnames = configurationProvider.RabbitMQNodes.Split(';');
                c.ClusterMembers = hostnames;
            });
        });

        host.Settings.GetConnectionFactory().Endpoint.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;

        x.AddConsumer<ObjectAddedHandler>().Endpoint(e => e.Name = "ObjectAddedHandler "+configurationProvider.TenantName);

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(container);
    }));

});



internal class ObjectAddedHandler : IConsumer<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent> context)
    {
        var @event = context.Message;
        await HandleAsync(@event).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}


internal class ObjectAddedHandlerConsumerDefinition :
            ConsumerDefinition<ObjectAddedHandler>
{
    private readonly IConfigurationProvider _provider;

    public ObjectAddedHandlerConsumerDefinition(IConfigurationProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;

        EndpointName = "ObjectAddedHandler" + provider.TenantName;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
    IConsumerConfigurator<ObjectAddedHandler> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        if (endpointConfigurator is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rabbit)
        {
            rabbit.BindMessageExchanges = false;

            rabbit.Bind("ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent", s =>
            {
                s.RoutingKey = _provider.TenantName;
                s.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

when the consumer is started the **ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent** direct exchange is created correctly. Also the **ObjectAddedHandlerTenant** fanout exchange (which should be the matching exchange) is created correctly.
Unfortunately when I try to **send** a message from the publisher side and I monitor the **ObjectAddedIntegrationEvent** direct exchange I see nothing coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the consumer definition, which should be added with your consumer using `AddConsumer<T>(typeof(definitionclass))`. It can be similar to this:

```
public class ObjectAddedHandlerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<ObjectAddedHandler>
{
    public ObjectAddedHandlerDefinition(IConfigurationProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;

        EndpointName = "ObjectAddedHandler" + provider.TenantName;

        ConcurrentMessageLimit = 4;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<ObjectAddedHandler> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        if(endpointConfigurator is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rabbit)
        {
            rabbit.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

            // or use Bind<T> for message type name
            rabbit.Bind("some-exchange", s => 
            {
                s.RoutingKey = _provider.TenantName;
                s.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks first of all because this is already helping. Unfortunately it doesn't work yet. I updated my question with the publisher side too.

Comment: There you go, and yeah, you'd need to use publish with this approach.